# django: RelatedManager for chained relations objects

Tags: django, django-orm

So I've got models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Grandchild(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Child', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ParentPhoto(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()

class ChildPhoto(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Child', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()

class GrandchildPhoto(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Grandchild', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Please ignore the bad database/models design (it's just an analogy to my complex real-life application).

I want to add a `RelatedManager` for `Parent` named maybe `family_photo_set` that would return a `Queryset` containing all `Photos` for himself, his `Children` and all `Children'` `Grandchildren`. How do I achieve that? A simple `RelatedManager` allows me to only filter somehow a `Parents'` `parentphoto_set`, not really adding the rest of family members.

Comment: Do you stop at three levels deep, or can there be an arbitrary number of levels?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - yes, I stop at three levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found a work-around. Posting for other visitors.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_family_photos(self):
        family_photos = []
        family_photos.extend(self.parentphoto_set.all())

        for child in self.child_set.all():
            family_photos.extend(child.childphoto_set.all)

            for grandchild in child.grandchild_set.all()):
                family_photos.extend(grandchild.grandchildphoto_set.all())

        return family_photos
```

This way I can use it e.g. in a template

```
{% for photo in parent.get_family_photos %}
(...)
```

Comment: +1 Every other solution with a queryset would require to modify models and to have only one class `Photo` with either a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) or three foreign keys. Please, accept your answer to be clear in the list of questions that you are not waiting for more answers.